# How to nicely scale a background image of a TextView for Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm battleing with extending a TextView for my Android app. I'd like to create "bubbles" to display text messages in a conversation, similar to the native iPhone SMS conversations.

Is there a way to implement the resizing of a background image without just stretching it? I'd like to have a single background image that keeps it's corners but get stretched only in defined areas. I think this should be possible because I've seen it in a SMS app, but I wonder how to implement that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a 9.patch image.  See [draw 9 patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) documentation.