# Android wrap_content and fill_parent at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to achieve something like this:
I have one picture to set as a background on layout in which is also TextView. So I want that layout to set his height to wrap content (which should be the height of TextView) and ImageView to has fill_parent as height and width.

I tried using:

- LinearLayout with background and TextView
- TextView with background
- RelativeLayout with ImageView (set height to fill_parent) and TextView (set to wrap_content)

Is there a way to do this?

Sorry, if it's next question about the same, but I have no idea how to find a solution.

EDIT:

I'll try to be more specific. I want a TextView with background. But I want that background to be scaled to fit TextView which should be wrap_content width and wrap_content height. But I have image in higher resolution so there is a lot of unused space (background doesn't scale).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, I can't really understand you. Draw a picture of what you want maybe

Comment: I hoped something better will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there is no way to set a view's width/height to both `wrap_content` and `fill_parent` simultaneously.
2. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is this what you mean?

   ```
   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       ...
       android:background="@drawable/image" >

       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           ... >
       </TextView>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

### EDIT

If you want to nicely scale a background image for a `TextView`, I think what you might want to look into is a 9-patch image. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6151311/844882) post for more info. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3479779/844882).

Comment: But image has gradient and one fragment that can't be scaled (it's comic balloon)